# Sony WH-H910n not recognized as a headphone in Windows 11

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, windows-11

I have sony WH-H910n headphones, I am not able to connect them to my pc through Bluetooth, When I try connecting it, the device name appears but not as a headphone. I have tried updating the drivers, doing a factory reset, etc, but nothing worked, It connects without any issues in my phone. How can I fix this?

Comment: I did not see any Windows 11 drivers at all. Firmware to V2.02 - that may help.  If it will not connect, you may need Windows 11 compliant headphones.

Comment: I updated it to the latest version, but still it does not appear, I don't think its an operating system related issue as I have tried to connect it to win10 and linux and still does not work